# Bing Image Search API prices

Tags: bing-api, azure-cognitive-services

I'm looking under "Bing Image Search API" at https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/pricing

I'm not sure I understand what benefit "S3 Standard" has over "S2 Standard"?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question.

Comment: Although the table clearly shows that S3 gets you 10 times as many calls per month as S2.

Comment: JJJ, thanks for your reply. Is there any issue to get 100K calls with S2? S2 is 10K calls with overage at $30 per 10K so I wonder if overage has any limits...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

S2 = 50 TPS, 10k calls/month, allows overage at listed overage rate (review pricing pricing page).

S3 = 100 TPS, 100k calls/month, allows overage at listed overage rate (review pricing page)

Main difference is the transactions per second (TPS).

Comment: Thanks! The lack of TPS in the pricing page confused me as I didn't see why anyone would select S3 over S2. With the TPS info, it all makes sense.